# I am having issue with creating webView on Xcode. Simulator appears to be blank white page. I applied app transport security

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview

I am having problem with creating webView in my project. I searched the same question on stackoverflow.com but all of them are pointing the info.list adding to App Transport Security (Allow Arbitrary Loads YES). I did it, but still I am getting blank white webpage. I used "http://www.google.com" just for simple try. Anyone can help? Is it related with new release of Swift?

```
 webView = UIWebView()
    webView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:20, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height-20)

    //after the adjustment, add webView to view panel.
    self.view.addSubview(webView)

    let url = URL(string: "https://wwww.google.com")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: I am very sorry original code has "http instead of https" but both of them did not work.

Comment: where do you pass URL to WebView?

Comment: It looks like you haven't call `load(_:)` on webview, call `webView.load(request)`

Comment: After that I used load request but sorry I forgot to add this line. @JuicyFruit

Comment: I might be sounds silly but should I add request to GET method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading the same link in a web browser. The initials could change according to your region. Like, it's "https://www.google.co.in/" here. 
Also try bringing the webView to the front

```
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: webView)
```

Comment: Hey, it worked, local change necessary for the browser! thanks!

Comment: @ErmanŞahinTatar You are welcome! Happy coding.. Since you are swift developer you could like this page on Facebook. New updates are added everyday.
https://www.facebook.com/iosswiftdevelopers/

Answer (score 0):

"You need to Bind URLRequest in Your object Of UIWebView "

```
 webView = UIWebView()
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    let url = URL(string: "https://wwww.google.com")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
     webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for help!! It turns out that I need local region addition to google, how silly I am I did not recognize it! :D